# C++ sscanf seams not to working as intended

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I'm currently working on project for school with an Arduino Uno and came across an issue with C sscanf  function. The code bellow is parsing a char array sent over the serial interface to the Arduino. Each data block is separated with a blankspace. I also checked similar question on Stackoverflow but found nothing helpful.

```
    char testInput[] = "t 1 3 65 1";

    int registerIndex;
    int locoAddr;
    int locoSpeed;
    int locoDirection;

   if(sscanf(testInput, "t %d %d %d %d", &registerIndex, &locoAddr, &locoSpeed, &locoDirection) != 4) {
        return;
    }

    // print for demo:
    Serial.print(registerIndex);
    Serial.print(": ");

    Serial.print("loco:");
    Serial.print(locoAddr);

    Serial.print(" speed:");
    Serial.print(locoSpeed);

    Serial.print(" direction:");
    Serial.println(locoDirection);

// expected output: "1: loco:3 speed:65 direction:1"
// output: "-18248: loco:-18248 speed:-18248 direction:-18248"
```

the sscanf function returns the expected integer 4 but doesn't fill the variables with the values so only the default values are printed.

I'm out of ideas what the issue could be. Maybe someone on the internet has a solution.

**Edit 1:** For better understanding of the complexity of the sketch this might help to understand the code a bit better:

1. loop in .ino file calls static Commander::process().
2. Commander::_readLine(...); get called and reads the data from serial.
3. some more validation is done but should not matter in this case
4. Commander::parseCommand(command); get called with the command.
5. registers->setThrottle(command); gets called when the command starts with a "t". registers is volatile so I'm able to call it from the interupt.
6. in PackageRegisterList::setThrottle is the sscanf method located.

Comment: "Each data block is separated with a blankspace." Try putting a space at the begginning of the format spec, as `" t %d %d %d %d"`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce by copying the snippet into a C program that outputs with `fprintf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane the provided code sample doesn't work. The first char of the provided input is "t" followed by an blankspace.  The "t" was used in a switch statement to determent what type of input it is before sscanf gets called .

Comment: It works here on my desktop PC. There must be more to it, which if the `'t'` was provided to use for a switch, there is. Was your *actual* code reading the `'t'` with `%c`? If so, place a space in front of `%c`, but as I say, cannot reproduce the problem so it is guesswork.

Comment: @WeatherVane when I tried it in a new sketch all works fine. Might be an issue with the memory of the Arduino? log: "1: loco:3 speed:65 direction:1". I might have to rethink some stuff....

Comment: Please don't blame the Arduino. It's 99.9999% ones own code, or understanding.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, it's my fault but I'm not sure what the issue could be. this might help to understand the code a bit better:
1) loop in .ino file calls static Commander::process(). 2) Commander::_readLine(); get called and reads the data from Serial. 3) Commander::parseCommand(command); get called with the command. 4) registers->setThrottle(command); gets called when the command starts with a "t".
5) in PackageRegisterList::setThrottle is the sscanf method located.

Comment: Yannik, please [edit] your question with new information. As you see, comments are just for that, to comment.

Comment: You might like to provide a [example].

Comment: I would discourage you from using `scanf` on the system which has 2k of RAM.

Comment: @thebusybee It's a bit difficult to provide a minimal reproducible example. The only thing I can do is provide you access the github repo...

Comment: Since `Serial.print` is overloaded and can take either a `char *` or an `int` argument, this clearly has nothing to do with C.  The C tag should be removed.  C++ is a different language.  Please stop using the name `C` for `C++` topics.

Comment: @0___________ what would be a better solution? manually splitting the char array?

Comment: @Yannik for sure. And it will save you 30% of flash as well :)

Comment: You can start by removing irrelevant parts, until it is minimal and still reveals the problem, or until you found the error in your code. You don't expect us to pull your code and do all this, do you?

Comment: @0___________ Why do you think `scanf()` (which isn't used here, but `sscanf()`) is to avoid with 2 KiB of RAM? I used it successfully on systems with 128 bytes. Dogmas are bad advices.

Comment: @thebusybee no of curse not! Just wondering what I should remove to provide a bare minimum of functional code. I'll try the input of other users and will come back to the idea of providing a minimal example. Thanks.

Comment: Dear community,
I'm not able to reproduce this issue again with a different sketch. I "fixed" the issue by avoiding doing this part of the application on my own. A library offers the exact required functionality and this sscanf call is now obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this version stolen from the Linux kernel:

```
int ASCII_vsscanf(const char * buf, const char * fmt, va_list args)
{
    const char *str = buf;
    char *next;
    char digit;
    int num = 0;
    int qualifier;
    int base;
    int field_width;
    int is_sign = 0;

    while(*fmt && *str) {
        /* skip any white space in format */
        /* white space in format matchs any amount of
         * white space, including none, in the input.
         */
        if (isspace(*fmt)) {
            while (isspace(*fmt))
                ++fmt;
            while (isspace(*str))
                ++str;
        }

        /* anything that is not a conversion must match exactly */
        if (*fmt != '%' && *fmt) {
            if (*fmt++ != *str++)
                break;
            continue;
        }

        if (!*fmt)
            break;
        ++fmt;

        /* skip this conversion.
         * advance both strings to next white space
         */
        if (*fmt == '*') {
            while (!isspace(*fmt) && *fmt)
                fmt++;
            while (!isspace(*str) && *str)
                str++;
            continue;
        }

        /* get field width */
        field_width = -1;
        if (isdigit(*fmt))
            field_width = skip_atoi(&fmt);

        /* get conversion qualifier */
        qualifier = -1;
        if (*fmt == 'h' || *fmt == 'l' || *fmt == 'L' ||
            *fmt == 'Z' || *fmt == 'z') {
            qualifier = *fmt++;
            if (unlikely(qualifier == *fmt)) {
                if (qualifier == 'h') {
                    qualifier = 'H';
                    fmt++;
                } else if (qualifier == 'l') {
                    qualifier = 'L';
                    fmt++;
                }
            }
        }
        base = 10;
        is_sign = 0;

        if (!*fmt || !*str)
            break;

        switch(*fmt++) {
        case 'c':
        {
            char *s = (char *) va_arg(args,char*);
            if (field_width == -1)
                field_width = 1;
            do {
                *s++ = *str++;
            } while (--field_width > 0 && *str);
            num++;
        }
        continue;
        case 's':
        {
            char *s = (char *) va_arg(args, char *);
            if(field_width == -1)
                field_width = INT_MAX;
            /* first, skip leading white space in buffer */
            while (isspace(*str))
                str++;

            /* now copy until next white space */
            while (*str && !isspace(*str) && field_width--) {
                *s++ = *str++;
            }
            *s = '\0';
            num++;
        }
        continue;
        case 'n':
            /* return number of characters read so far */
        {
            int *i = (int *)va_arg(args,int*);
            *i = str - buf;
        }
        continue;
        case 'o':
            base = 8;
            break;
        case 'x':
        case 'X':
            base = 16;
            break;
        case 'i':
                        base = 0;
        case 'd':
            is_sign = 1;
        case 'u':
            break;
        case '%':
            /* looking for '%' in str */
            if (*str++ != '%')
                return num;
            continue;
        default:
            /* invalid format; stop here */
            return num;
        }

        /* have some sort of integer conversion.
         * first, skip white space in buffer.
         */
        while (isspace(*str))
            str++;

        digit = *str;
        if (is_sign && digit == '-')
            digit = *(str + 1);

        if (!digit
                    || (base == 16 && !isxdigit(digit))
                    || (base == 10 && !isdigit(digit))
                    || (base == 8 && (!isdigit(digit) || digit > '7'))
                    || (base == 0 && !isdigit(digit)))
                break;

        switch(qualifier) {
        case 'H':   /* that's 'hh' in format */
            if (is_sign) {
                signed char *s = (signed char *) va_arg(args,signed char *);
                *s = (signed char) ASCII_simple_strtol(str,&next,base);
            } else {
                unsigned char *s = (unsigned char *) va_arg(args, unsigned char *);
                *s = (unsigned char) ASCII_simple_strtoul(str, &next, base);
            }
            break;
        case 'h':
            if (is_sign) {
                short *s = (short *) va_arg(args,short *);
                *s = (short) ASCII_simple_strtol(str,&next,base);
            } else {
                unsigned short *s = (unsigned short *) va_arg(args, unsigned short *);
                *s = (unsigned short) ASCII_simple_strtoul(str, &next, base);
            }
            break;
        case 'l':
            if (is_sign) {
                long *l = (long *) va_arg(args,long *);
                *l = ASCII_simple_strtol(str,&next,base);
            } else {
                unsigned long *l = (unsigned long*) va_arg(args,unsigned long*);
                *l = ASCII_simple_strtoul(str,&next,base);
            }
            break;
        case 'L':
            if (is_sign) {
                long long *l = (long long*) va_arg(args,long long *);
                *l = ASCII_simple_strtoll(str,&next,base);
            } else {
                unsigned long long *l = (unsigned long long*) va_arg(args,unsigned long long*);
                *l = ASCII_simple_strtoull(str,&next,base);
            }
            break;
        case 'Z':
        case 'z':
        {
            size_t *s = (size_t*) va_arg(args,size_t*);
            *s = (size_t) ASCII_simple_strtoul(str,&next,base);
        }
        break;
        default:
            if (is_sign) {
                int *i = (int *) va_arg(args, int*);
                *i = (int) ASCII_simple_strtol(str,&next,base);
            } else {
                unsigned int *i = (unsigned int*) va_arg(args, unsigned int*);
                *i = (unsigned int) ASCII_simple_strtoul(str,&next,base);
            }
            break;
        }
        num++;

        if (!next)
            break;
        str = next;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Limited but small and good enough for me.